# How can I take the previous 5 values I am passing through search and then using it in API. I want to display pervious five values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

This is a functional component. Here I am using useEffect hook to hit API on the dependency of search. The place where I am doing console.log(`${search}` is displaying the current search in the console. How can I take the last five searches in an array and then display them?

````
    const [city, setCity] = useState(null);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("Dehradun");


useEffect ( () => {
        const fetchApi = async () => {
            const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${search}&units=metric&appid=7938d9005e68d8b258a109c716436c91`
            const response = await fetch(url);
            fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${search}&units=metric&appid=7938d9005e68d8b258a109c716436c91")
            .then(result => console.log(`${search}`, result))
            const resJson = await response.json();
            setCity(resJson.main);
        };
        fetchApi();

    },[search] )```
````

Comment: you can track it on another state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is able to keep track of previous searches as you expect. It just stacks the previous response to an array along with the result and excludes items from the end when the size exceeds more than 5.

```js
function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = React.useState("Dehradun");
  const [searchHistory, setSearchHistory] = React.useState([]);

  const doSearch = () => {
    if (search.length > 0) {
      fetch(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${search}&units=metric&appid=7938d9005e68d8b258a109c716436c91`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
          setSearchHistory((prevState) => [
            [search, result],
            ...prevState.slice(0, 4)
          ]);
          setSearch("");
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} value={search} />
      <button onClick={doSearch}>search</button>
      {searchHistory.map(([search, result], index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <b>{search}</b> : {JSON.stringify(result)}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```